# Webservice.asmx not receiving parameters with POST/SOAP requests

Tags: c#, php, web-services, soap, mono

I am trying to send data to a C# (actually Mono) webservice from a PHP environment. Oddly, the webservice works correctly when I call it with a browser URL (i.e. with the GET method).

However, calling it from my PHP script shows that no parameter is received on Mono's side.

Here is my PHP call:

```
$domoWSHeader->setAuthenticatedToken($resultAuthentification->AuthentificationResult);
$inputHeaders = new SoapHeader("http://tempuri.org/domo", "DomoWSHeader", $domoWSHeader, false);
$result = $soapClient->__soapCall("MyWebServiceMethod", array("idLight"=>$uuid), NULL, $inputHeaders);
```

And the Webservices.asmx looks like:

```
namespace domo
{
    public class DomoWSHeader : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader
    {
            public string username;
            public string password;
            public string authenticatedToken;
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public bool MyWebServiceMethod(int idLight)
    {
    bool success = false;
        //Snip
        return success;
    }
}
```

**What have I tried?**
Trying to declare `[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeader("DomoWSHeader")]` before the method didn't change the behaviour.

I also tried to edit the `web.config` file to add protocols in it. I am totally new to the C# world, and I am not sure where to find answers to this problem. I hope one of you can help me understand what happens here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the origin of the problem from PHP.NET : http://php.net/manual/fr/soapclient.soapcall.php#110390

In the PHP code, the parameters in the "__soapCall()" method were :

```
$parameters = array("idLight" => $uuid);
```

but it's correct when you use them to call the webservice method directly as :

```
$soapClient->NameOfTheMethod($parameters);
```

In my case, i'd need to call the webservice method with "__soapCall()" because i use headers for authentication, and the PHP.NET documentation says that we must encapsulate the array of parameters into another array like this :

```
$soapClient->__soapCall("NameOfTheMethod", array($parameters), NULL, $inputHeaders);
```

(Note that the 3rd and the 4th parameters in the "__soapCall()" method are optionals but i use them)

Hope this help :)